# Symfony2 - doctrine:create in Production

Tags: orm, symfony, doctrine-orm, production-environment

When using the command:

```
$ php app/console doctrine:schema:create
```

We get this message

> ATTENTION: This operation should not be executed in a production environment.

Why shouldn't we use it in production ?
How should we do the first deployment ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ahaha there are different schools for that.

- Startup way: doctrine:schema:create first time in production, doctrine:schema:update --force every updates
- Cautious way: dump sql first time, sql scripts then for updates
- Expert way: http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html

Personally I use the first method, which works just fine. You could always do a --dump-sql to see what's going on before updating using --force

Comment: Ha ok so this command CAN be used in production for the first time. I though it was told to never use it. Thanks for the details

Comment: Migrations are a joy to use and I would not say that they are "expert", they are quite easy to set up and work like a charm

Comment: I admit I never looked in detail migrations, just the concept and cookbok. I'll have a look

Comment: See also https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/commit/62a8e2aad57cdf41fa4828cf7e3d88c53400aecb